# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given Error on a very simple form function

Tags: python, django, django-templates, bootstrap-modal, typeerror

I have this very simple form but I keep getting the error

> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py

```
class Feedback_form(BSModalForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ['name', 'contact', 'title', 'description', 'summary']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
class Feedback_Create(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/feedback.html'
    form_class = Feedback_form
    success_message = 'Success: Sign up succeeded. You can now Log in.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('classroom:feedback_form')
```

urls.py

```
path('feedback/', teachers.Feedback_Create, name='feedback'),
```

feedback.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Create Book</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="{% if form.non_field_errors %}invalid{% endif %} mb-2">
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ error }}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label %}
        <div class="{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Create</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong here. I have installed the library just fine, and added the appropriate name in the installed_apps in settings file. I keep getting the error:

> TypeError at /shipper/feedback/
>   **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/shipper/feedback/
>   Django Version: 2.0.1
>   Exception Type: TypeError
>   Exception Value:
>   **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\idadarklord\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 21

I am trying to install a simple feedback popup form as shown [here](https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `login_required` on an class based view, if you want to do that you need to use `method_decorator`. Take a look at the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

And in your urls.py you need to call `.as_view()` for class based views.

```py
  path('feedback/', teachers.Feedback_Create.as_view(), name='feedback'),
```

Comment: I just removed decorator but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @RohitKumar Updated my answer you forgot to cal `as_view` on you class view. Also its more pythonic/convention to not use underscore in your class names `FeedbackCreate`

Comment: I tried that too, but when I use the as_view(), it gives me an error that says 2 arguments were given instead of 1.

Comment: You did both the changes? Because based on what you are showing those changes should fix it. Also take a look at the marked duplicate answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572251/django-2-1-3-error-init-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)