# How to fix TypeError when using django-restframework-generics

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I am learning how to use class-based generic views but I keep getting a type error

```
from invoice.models import Invoice
from invoice.serializers import InvoiceSerializer
from rest_framework import generics


class InvoiceList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer


class InvoiceDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer
```

```
serialzers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Invoice


class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = "__all__"
```

```
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from invoice import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('invoice/', views.InvoiceList),
    path('invoice/<int:pk>/', views.InvoiceDetail),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

I get a type error with the message "**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: Share your serializer and url code. Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572251/django-2-1-3-error-init-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)! or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)! it might help you understand the error.

Comment: @Zoro-Zen added the serializer and urlcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import in urls.py looks wrong.
In urls.py, try something like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import InvoiceList

path('invoice/', InvoiceList.as_view(), name="invoice"), # name can be anything you want.
```

I never used the format_suffix_patterns, so you can try to take off that line to see if it works.