# Stripe Integration with Django giving a type error saying __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, stripe-payments

Hi I've been trying to learn how to integrate the Stripe prebuilt checkout page into my django project.

The stripe docs are for flask so I'm trying to read or watch youtube tutorials on how to convert them into django but I'm not really getting anywhere. The code in the tutorials are different from the current stripe docs

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
# Create your views here.
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


class ProductLandingPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "landing.html"


class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View):
    def post(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        YOUR_DOMAIN = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=[
                {
                    # TODO: replace this with the `price` of the product you want to sell
                    'price': '{{PRICE_ID}}',
                    'quantity': 1,
                },
            ],
            mode='payment',
            success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + "/success",
            cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + "/cancel",
        )

        return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)


class Successview(TemplateView):
    template_name = "success.html"


class Cancelview(TemplateView):
    template_name = "cancel.html"
```

I can get the checkout.html to show but when I click on the checkout button I get this error

```
TypeError at /create-checkout-session
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create-checkout-session
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\TYS\\Desktop\\Web Development\\Django\\stripetest_project',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\TYS\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\ibapi-9.76.1-py3.9.egg',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Tue, 17 Aug 2021 03:52:08 +0000
```

I've also tried the code on this page

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
# Create your views here.
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


class ProductLandingPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "landing.html"


class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View):
    def post(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        YOUR_DOMAIN = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=[{
                'price_data': {
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': 'T-shirt',
                    },
                    'unit_amount': 2000,
                },
                'quantity': 1,
            }],
            mode='payment',
            success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + "/success",
            cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + "/cancel",
        )

        return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)


class Successview(TemplateView):
    template_name = "success.html"


class Cancelview(TemplateView):
    template_name = "cancel.html"
```

and still get the same error

Can anyone help me fix it?

Thanks

edit:adding urls.py and also the landing.html for reference

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from products.views import CreateCheckoutSessionView, ProductLandingPageView, Cancelview, Successview

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cancel/', Cancelview.as_view(), name='cancel'),
    path('success/', Successview.as_view(), name='success'),
    path('create-checkout-session', CreateCheckoutSessionView, name='create-checkout-session'),
    path('', ProductLandingPageView.as_view(), name='landing-page')


]
```

this is the landing.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Buy cool new product</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="product">
        <img
          src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
          alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"
        />
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Stubborn Attachments</h3>
          <h5>$20.00</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
      </form>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your urls.py

Comment: Hi, have added the urls.py and also the landing.html. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I added an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is related to missing `as_view()` in your `path` definitions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572256/12474862

It does not seem to be a Stripe-related error, but something in the Django configuration.

Comment: OMG, I'm an idiot! Thank you so much. I thought it was something so much more complex and it's just a silly mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update your urls.py:

```
    path('create-checkout-session', CreateCheckoutSessionView.as_view(), name='create-checkout-session'),
```

Comment: OMG, I'm an idiot! Thank you so much. I thought it was something so much more complex and it's just a silly mistake. Thanks